# When transferring photos from iPhone to computer, is it better to have selected "automatic" or "keep originals"?

Tags: iphone, file-transfer, backup

When transferring photos from iPhone 7 to computer, is it better to have selected "automatic" or "keep originals"? Which setting would transfer the photos with the highest quality?

Answer (score 1):

**"Keep originals" is most likely to preserve the best possible quality.**

Comment: This is another 'misunderstanding how iCloud works' question. Keep originals is only useful if you have a lot of space on your local device.